# Highlight a file using java

Tags: windows

I need to open a folder from my **java** program and make a specific file **highlighted**.
For example when i press one Jbutton(inside the program)(i have the file path) i want the
**parent** folder containing the **specific** file to be opened and (the spesific file be **highlighted**).
Thanks..

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "highlighting a file"? And how do you want to "open" the file? Sounds like you are talking about a file manager? You have to be more specific in your question...

Comment: @arkascha you open a folder(with files) you select a file(you click one time on it)(for example on windows it goes blue color) thats what i want to   do  programatically..

Comment: So you are talking about a file manager, since the OS itself is not able to show you any files or the like. Obviously you have to consult the documentation of the file manager you want to use to learn how to achieve what you describe. There certainly is no general way, since this clearly depends on the program you want to "remote control" (the file manager).

Comment: Keep in mind that there is not "THE" file manager. There are many different ones. So there cannot be a general solution. An example: I (on my system) use the `dolphin` file manager. For this you can use: `dolphin --select <file-path>`. No programming required, it does exactly what you want. but these options may vary from file manager to file manager.

Comment: If there is not general i need a solution for windows... I have seen one question like this using Runtime.getRuntime() but it was a long time ago  and now i can't find it .. thanks for help anyway

Comment: Ah, you are talking about MS-Windows! Sorry, no idea about that. Like most programmers I stopped using that decades ago :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found this. For anyone who need a solution(For windows only)
[**On Other Systems**] althought it must be a similar program like (**explorer.exe**).

Using **RunTime**:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("explorer.exe /select,"+path);
```